# Conversion to dollar of one column of a matrix

Tags: r

Given:

```
> finish2
        I     C    R
1 7336.08 29.23 5.19
2 7740.92 34.31 5.09
3 6929.31 32.54 4.75
4 6589.42 27.00 4.06
5 5578.33 26.33 4.08
6 3912.17 24.17 4.47
7 4835.58 27.67 4.17

> finish3=as.character(finish2)
> finish3
 [1] "7336.08" "7740.92" "6929.31" "6589.42" "5578.33" "3912.17" "4835.58"
 [8] "29.23"   "34.31"   "32.54"   "27"      "26.33"   "24.17"   "27.67"  
[15] "5.19"    "5.09"    "4.75"    "4.06"    "4.08"    "4.47"    "4.17"   

class(finish2) #a numeric matrix
class(finish3) #character vector
```

Question:
I want to add  (paste0) a $ before values in R column
how to do?

```
> finish5=finish2[, 'R'] <- paste0('$', finish2[,'R'])
> finish5
[1] "$5.19" "$5.09" "$4.75" "$4.06" "$4.08" "$4.47" "$4.17"
> cbind(I,R,finish5)
  I                  R                  finish5
1 "7336.07692307692" "5.18769230769231" "$5.19"
2 "7740.92307692308" "5.08538461538462" "$5.09"
3 "6929.30769230769" "4.75461538461538" "$4.75"
4 "6589.41666666667" "4.05666666666667" "$4.06"
5 "5578.33333333333" "4.07583333333333" "$4.08"
6 "3912.16666666667" "4.475"            "$4.47"
7 "4835.58333333333" "4.17166666666667" "$4.17"
>
```

This is typical occurence when I cbind. I lose 2 place behind decimal point.
I have tried using a data.frame with similar results. Things have to be done in the correct order!

Comment: No. only column R

Comment: I don't get what is the issue here ? You don't need `finish5` or `cbind` here, if you do `finish2[, 'R'] <- paste0('$', finish2[,'R'])`, `finish2` already has the updated dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
finish2[, 'R'] <- paste0('$', finish2[,'R'])
```

but this will change all the values in the matrix `finish2` to character since a `matrix` can hold only one class.

You can convert `finish2` to `data.frame` instead which can have different class for different columns.

```
type.convert(data.frame(finish2))

#     I     C     R
#1 7336 29.23 $5.19
#2 7741 34.31 $5.09
#3 6929 32.54 $4.75
#4 6589 27.00 $4.06
#5 5578 26.33 $4.08
#6 3912 24.17 $4.47
#7 4836 27.67 $4.17
```

So here we'll have `I` and `C` as `numeric` columns and `R` as `factor`.

**data**

```
finish2 <- structure(c(7336.08, 7740.92, 6929.31, 6589.42, 5578.33, 3912.17, 
4835.58, 29.23, 34.31, 32.54, 27, 26.33, 24.17, 27.67, 5.19, 
5.09, 4.75, 4.06, 4.08, 4.47, 4.17), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), c("I", "C", "R")))
```